# Azure Function deployment using VS code

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have created a function app in Azure. Using Visual Studio Code, I created a function in local, and deployed it to existing function app.

The first time I deployed, it was successful.

The second time, however, when I deployed the same function from local to the same existing function app, the `http_trigger` inside the function app disappeared.

After that, I tried the deployment multiple times, but still the `http_trigger` is not found.

Why did it get removed on the second deployment? Should I deploy the function only once?

If yes, is there any way to perform the deployment again, in case of any changes in the code inside the function?

I have the script file `test_run.py` with some code, inside the function in the `function_app.py` file, I tried to import my script file like below, after making these changes, I tried for deployment when the `http_trigger` got removed.

`function_app.py`:

```
import test_run

rest of the default trigger function code

if name:
   test_run.main()
   return f"Hello {name}. The function triggered"
else:
   test_run.main()
   return f"Hello. The function triggered without a name"
```

`test_run.py`:

```
def func_1():
   function code

def func_2():
   function code

def func_3():
   function code

def main ():
   try:
       func_1()
       func_2()
       func_3()
   except:
       code for retry
```

I was also not able to create only the `http_trigger` inside the function, that option is not available for me in either vs code or in Azure Portal.

Also, if I create the new function and function app from scratch, it was deployed the first time successfully. When I do some changes in the script and try to deploy it again, the `http_trigger` got removed.

Please help me to resolve this.

**Doc Screenshot:**
[image]

**Error screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT can you help me with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an issue with the VS code extension while which is causing your function app to not deploy again after you make the code changes. Ideally if you deploy your local trigger multiple times, It will get deployed with the new code successfully in the Function app in portal.

As a workaround, Make sure you have [**Function core tools installed**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows,isolated-process,node-v4,python-v2,http-trigger,container-apps&pivots=programming-language-csharp) and use the below commands in your VS code to deploy the Function multiple times in the Function app like below:-

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription "Subscription name"
func azure functionapp publish functionappname
```

[image]

[image]

***I also made some changes to your code and used sys.path method to import the test_run.py file in my code like below:-***

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import os


current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_dir))

 # import 'test_run' module
from test_run import func_1, func_2, func_3

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        func_1()  
        func_2()
        func_3()

        name = req.params.get('name')
        if not name:
            return func.HttpResponse("Please pass a 'name' parameter in the query string.", status_code=400)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}. The function triggered successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

Comment: but the documentation says that the Function core tools installation is not mandatory. can you please explain more how its related to the issue I am facing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=node-v3%2Cpython-v2%2Cisolated-process&pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: also for the commands you have provided I am getting only the errors. Please find the screenshots posted in the question.

Comment: For the az commands to work you need to install azure cli in your machine, refer here for installing it in windows os -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: It is working on my end with vs code too, Are you logged in to your Azure account in vs code successfully and are able to see all resources correctly?

Comment: yes logged in to my Azure account in vs code, able to see all the resources, the only issue is with azure function deployment.

Comment: when I trigger the function, I am getting the error https://imgur.com/XFD3vDn

Comment: In your input in code + test pass the parameters > I have passed - name and value as sid

Comment: yes, I have passed the parameter "name":"Azure"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255540/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-beginner).